# MySQL order by ABS if numeric

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I need to order some information with order by in a MySQL query. Is there a possibility to use  the ABS function only if the first char is numeric?

Pseudo example:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY
(( name[0] = numeric ) ? ABS(name) : name)
ASC
```

---

Thanks for the answers so far, tried a lot with your answers but I don't get the result I want.

The current code:

```
<?php
$filters = $this->db->query("
    SELECT
        tb_spec_feature.feature_id,
        tb_spec_feature.name
    FROM
        tb_spec_feature
    WHERE
        filter=1
");
$filters = $filters->result_array();
foreach($filters as $key=>$filter)
{
    $filters_sub = $this->db->query("
        SELECT DISTINCT
            tb_spec_value.value_id,
            tb_spec_value.name as value_name,
            tb_spec_sign.name as sign_name
        FROM
            tb_spec_fk
        INNER JOIN
            tb_spec_value
        ON
            tb_spec_value.value_id = tb_spec_fk.value
        LEFT JOIN
            tb_spec_sign
        ON
            tb_spec_sign.sign_id = tb_spec_fk.sign
        WHERE
            feature=".$this->db->escape($filter['feature_id'])."
        ORDER BY
            ABS(tb_spec_value.name) ASC
    ");
    $filters[$key]['values'] = $filters_sub->result_array();
}
?>
```

This will output (tb_spec_feature.name and then the tb_spec_value.name):

**Screen inches**

- 7
- 7.7
- 7.9
- 8.9
- 9.7
- 10
- 10.1
- 12.1

**Resolution**

- 800 x 480
- 1024 x 600
- 1024 x 768
- 1280 x 800
- 1280 x 768
- 1920 x 1200
- 2048 x 1536

**Operating system**

- Android 3.1
- Android
- BlackBerry Tablet OS
- Android 3.2
- Android 2.3
- Android 4.0
- iOS 5
- Android 4.0.3
- iOS 4
- Android 2.2
- Windows 7 Professional
- Windows 8
- Windows 8 Pro
- iOS 6

As you can see the inches and resolutions are okay, but the operating systems aren't ordered well. If I remove the ABS the result will be:

**Screen inches**

- 10
- 10.1
- 12.1
- 7
- 7.7
- 7.9
- 8.9
- 9.7

**Resolution**

- 1024 x 600
- 1024 x 768
- 1280 x 768
- 1280 x 800
- 1366 x 768
- 1920 x 1200
- 2048 x 1536
- 800 x 480

**Operating system**

- Android
- Android 2.2
- Android 2.3
- Android 3.1
- Android 3.2
- Android 4.0
- Android 4.0.3
- BlackBerry Tablet OS
- iOS 4
- iOS 5
- iOS 6
- Windows 7 Professional
- Windows 8
- Windows 8 Pro

As you can see now, the operating systems are ordered well but the inches and resolutions not.. I hope somebody can help me out :)

Comment: If you're using `ABS()`, doesn't that imply that numbers can be negative and the first character could also be `-`?

Comment: oh please not... if the first letter is a numeric, you would not need abs(), because the minus would also be a letter (the first one). Please use a cast/convert function AND overthink your database design, this is eating hella-lot performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is the MySql way of your question:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN LEFT(name, 1)>='0' AND LEFT(name, 1)<='9' THEN ABS(name) 
     ELSE name 
     END ASC
```

(**Edit**)
But according to comments, is better for you:

```
ORDER BY ABS(name), name
```

That works in this way:
If ABS() can be applied to 'name' the numeric resulting value will be ordered, but in the opposite case, if ABS(name) evaluates to null (because a non numeric has no abs value) then the second field (name) on order by, is which is relevant to the sort.

Comment: I think this address what you asked but I cant figure its use case :)

Comment: I have read your update, can you let me know what do you get when you use the order by clause suggested here???

Comment: Sorry for my late response. When I run this the result is equal to the result like "ORDER BY tb_spec_value.name ASC". Any other ideas?

Comment: what about `order by ABS(name), name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
CASE WHEN LEFT(name[0], 1) LIKE [0-9] then ABS(name) ELSE name END
```

Assuming `name` as `numeric`

Comment: Perhaps you meant `name RLIKE '^[0-9]'`?

Answer (score 0):

you could use convert function:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CONVERT(name, SIGNED)
```

that will convert all non-numerics to 0 so you can safely pass it's result to functions that assume integer arguments:

```
ABS(CONVERT(name, SIGNED))
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! But, not with SQL..
I removed the ABS from the query and while handeling the query I use this:

```
<?
function order_it($a,$b)
{
    return $a["value_name"] - $b["value_name"];
}

foreach($filters as $key=>$filter)
{
    if(isset($filter['values'][0]['value_name'][0]) AND is_numeric($filter['values'][0]['value_name'][0]))
    {
        usort($filter['values'],'order_it');
    }
    foreach($filter['values'] as $item)
    {
        echo $item['value_name'].'<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Now everything is ordered correctly :)